# Antd Notification appearing twice?

Tags: reactjs, antd, setstate

I am using antd notification component as follows

```
        import { notification } from "antd";

        const Notification = ({ msg, type, clearMsg }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {notification[type]({
                description: msg,
              })}
              {clearMsg()}
            </div>
          );
        };

        export default Notification;
```

And I am simply using it anywhere I need a notification to pop-up. For instance after API response failure:

```
          const onSubmit = async (e) => {
            try {
              const res = await login(data);
              if (res.message) {
                setError({ state: true, msg: res.message });
              }
            } catch (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          };
```

And then depending on error state, I am showing the Notification in the return body as following:

```
          { error.state ?
            <Notification 
               type="error" 
               msg="some msg" 
               clearMsg={() => setError({state: false, msg: ""})} :
             null
          }
```

But simultaneously two pop-ups appear instead of just one, can anyone guide on why I am getting this behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you call directly notification[type]() from func onSubmit?

Answer (score 10):

I resolved my problem by using `notification.destroy();` before showing notification. An example below here:

```
const showNotification = () => {
    notification.destroy();
    notification.open({message: 'message here'});
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assign a unique identifier by using the `key` property. See: https://ant.design/components/notification/#API

```
const Notification = ({ key, msg, type, clearMsg }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {notification[type]({
        key,
        description: msg,
      })}
      {clearMsg()}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This worked well, I'm using NextJS 12 and React 18.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I was going nuts with this. Somehow my axios error interceptor is being called multiple times for a single requisition response. Setting a key to Notification worked quite well

Answer (score 0):

Should create a config object and passed it to useNotification method.

```
const config = {
  maxCount:1,
};

const Login = () => {
  const [api, contextHolder] = notification.useNotification(config);
  const openNotificationWithIcon = (type, message, description) => {
    api[type]({
      message: message,
      description: description,

    });
  };

   ...
   return (
           <Button
              type="primary"
              htmlType="submit"
              className="login-form-button"
              onClick={() =>
                openNotificationWithIcon("success", "login", "success")
              }
            >
              Log in
            </Button>
   )
```